# Custom rectangle Imageview with curve from top and bottom

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[image: Expected Imageview UI]

Hello, I am creating a image slider with viewpager and want to create a custom Imageview with curve from top and bottom for the item list in Java/Kotlin and set images from api I am able to create custom rectangle image but I am not aware of how to create curve from top and bottom.

Tried

1. Svg set to ImageView but shape changes once image is set dynamically.
2. Custom Image class by extending Imageview

Comment: Is it in custom view from kotlin/java class or Jetpack compose ? Please specify it

Comment: @PratikFagadiya Java/Kotlin class

Comment: @Rakesh A quick hack can be to use another ImageView on top of your main imageView and add the svg to upper imageView, and match your svg color to background color of screen, the svg will hide the image view at relevant places, making it appear rounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this kind of shape in `ImageView` by extending the `com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView` and change the default `ShapeAppearanceModel`. Using the `ShapeAppearanceModel` you can apply a custom `EdgeTreatment` to draw a curve in the top edge and bottom edge. Also it has helper methods to draw the corners to `CornerFamily.ROUNDED` or `CornerFamily.CUT`. Example is like the below:

1.Create a subclass of **ShapeableImageView**:

```
public class CustomImageView extends ShapeableImageView {

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){

        //set the curveOffset and cornerRadius in pixels
        int curveOffset = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int cornerRadius = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        //set the new ShapeAppearanceModel
        ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = getShapeAppearanceModel()
                .toBuilder()
                .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, cornerRadius)
                .setTopEdge(new EdgeTreatment(){
                    @Override
                    public void getEdgePath(float length, float center, float interpolation, @NonNull ShapePath shapePath) {
                        shapePath.quadToPoint(length/2, curveOffset, length, 0f);
                    }
                })
                .setBottomEdge(new EdgeTreatment(){
                    @Override
                    public void getEdgePath(float length, float center, float interpolation, @NonNull ShapePath shapePath) {
                        shapePath.quadToPoint(length/2, curveOffset, length, 0f);
                    }
                })
                .build();
        setShapeAppearanceModel(shapeAppearanceModel);
    }
}
```

2.Use it in your xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <my.package.name.CustomImageView
        android:id="@+id/shapeImageView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_action_chat"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Result:**

[image: shape_image_view]

**Sample usage in a `RecyclerView` using **Glide** image loading library:**

1.Declare the `CustomImageView` in your list item xml in the same way as above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <my.package.name.CustomImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2.Load the images into the **CustomImageView** using **Glide** in on `onBindViewHolder` like the below:

```
int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 250, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 150, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
Glide.with(context)
        .load(model.getUrl())
        .override(width, height)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(holder.imageView);
```

**Result in a RecyclerView:**

[image: recyclerview_sample]

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to create a custom ImageView with overriden onDraw method.
In this method you should create a path using bezier curve and then draw image inside.
More information about custom drawing is on https://www.kodeco.com/9556022-drawing-custom-shapes-in-android?page=2#toc-anchor-011
and https://medium.com/@pranjalg2308/understanding-bezier-curve-in-android-and-moddinggraphview-library-a9b1f0f95cd0

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a **Curved Shape Drawable:**

```
class CurvedShapeDrawable : Drawable() {
private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
    color = Color.BLUE // Set your desired color here
}

override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
    val width = bounds.width().toFloat()
    val height = bounds.height().toFloat()
    
    val path = Path().apply {
        moveTo(0f, height)
        lineTo(0f, height * 0.8f)
        quadTo(width * 0.5f, height * 0.6f, width, height * 0.8f)
        lineTo(width, height)
        close()
    }

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint)
}

// Override other methods like `setAlpha`, `setColorFilter`, and `getOpacity`
}
```

After creating the custom `Drawable`, apply it to your `ImageView` using the background property.

```
val curvedShapeDrawable = CurvedShapeDrawable()
imageView.background = curvedShapeDrawable
```

To load `images` from an API and display them in your `ViewPager`, you'll need an image loading library like `Glide` or `Picasso`.

```
// Add Glide dependency to your build.gradle
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'

// Load images using Glide
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageUrl) // Replace with your image URL from the API
    .into(imageView)
```

Try this, hope so it'll solved your problem.